# NodeJS: access using domain without port

Tags: node.js, deployment, domain-name

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7) to deploy NodeJS my app on the server.
My issue is that, I only can access the service using domain:port (example.com:1234) not domain name only (example.com).

How can I configure my app to access the service without adding the port to the address/domain name?

Answer (score 3):

TCP connections always require you, the client, to specify a port. You're able to visit `domain.com` in your browser without specifying a port because your browser implicitly connects on the conventional ports: **80** for HTTP and **443** for HTTPS.

Your application server needs to bind to one of these ports in order to achieve what you're going for.

EDIT: Just skimmed the tutorial you linked to. Since your application is sitting behind a reverse proxy , you'll need NGINX to own 80/ 443 (which it should do by default). You can bind the app server to whatever port you want, so long as the reverse proxy config matches up with it.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean in the last sentence in your edit. can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Sure. Your app architecture has two high level components: the node http server and the nginx web server. When a user visits your site, they're really connecting to nginx, not node. Once the connection is made, nginx passes the data along to the node server (hence, "proxy pass") which implements your actual business logic. The process that actually faces the web and receives connections is the one that needs to own the default http ports and in this case, that's nginx